# Winform - Force user to fill out form on startup

Tags: c#, winforms

Thanks in advance for the help.  I am primarily a web developer but have been tasked with creating a simple winforms application.  I have the application complete with the exception of one part.  This application will run on startup and prompt the user to enter a reason why they are using the machine.  Is there an easy way to force the user to fill out this form before continuing.  Basically I want disable everything (start menu, etc) until this form has been filled out and closed.

Could I kill explorer.exe then restart?  That seems kind of invasive to me.

Comment: You cannot (easily) block task manager

Comment: Are you saying there *is* a way?

Comment: @m.edmondson I've had a couple of viruses in the past that completely disable the task manager. Extremely annoying, of course, and very user-hostile, but possible. How? No idea :)

Comment: @Alex - Okay perhaps not impossible but certainly not the route ethical software should be taking

Comment: @m.edmondson definitely not. I'm wondering how the OP's problem is solved, though. You do get custom win shells at places like gaming cafes, where access to the machines is centrally controlled, but I have no idea how it's done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a custom [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) to add an extra textbox to the login screen might do it? Probably not for the faint-hearted though!

Comment: I need to find a custom GINA. Any kinda custom GINA. It's hard to rhyme a word like a GINA. Calvin Klein kinda? North Carolina...

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible as a savvy user can just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and kill the application.  There is no way you can either prevent or capture this event as it is the way Windows is designed from a security perspective.

Comment: You could in theory watch for "ctrl-alt-del" and throw away the result.  If you also made it not possible to close the application or take away its focus ( while loop within a timer ) you have a form that cannot be closed.  Of course event with this there is away around it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running Explorer.exe on login, you could run your own application. It is a simple setting in local computer policy to change this.

After the user is finished with your app, you could start explorer.exe or change the settings back to the default.

[Here's a small tutorial how to do this.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/UserInterface.aspx)

BTW: I don't use this on any computer, but in the (terminal Services) profile of all my users, I change this to run my own app on login. This is a normal .Net winforms application, originally not designed to run as a shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a tricky thing like this:

- Set the Form's `FormBorderProperty` to None, `Opacity` to 1% and `WindowState` to Maximized
- On the Load event of this form generate a new form with your controls and show it as a dialog.

Don't sure whether it works in Windows-7 but works well in XP. This is not the proper solution, though it creates an illusion. The user can still skip this by pressing <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and kill the process.